# Where do you put MariaDB client options for multiple server instances?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have been setting up multiple mariadb instances on a server. The instances will be configured differently, depending on e.g. whether they are geared towards MyISAM or InnoDB tables. I am happy about the main server configuration, e.g. create a file called /etc/my.cnf.d/innodb.cnf with a section headed [mysqld.innodb] and start the database with "systemctl start mariadb@innodb", but what do I do about sections like [mysqldump] and [myisamchk]? Do these apply across all mariadb instances? If so, then should I move them to a separate file or files, rather than duplicating the sections in multiple files?

Answer (score 0):

Start each instance with its own `my.cnf`, or at least overrides.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/option-file-options.html